# Dealing with small devices hitting jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, android, css, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know if there are Android 2.X or higher devices out there with exceptionally small screens, like below say 250pixels and shorter than 300pixels?

The emulators all seem to have pretty big screens, and I'm wondering if these devices exists if there's a way to test them, or a good way for me to block them from my site using a media query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://kschang.hubpages.com/hub/The-7-Weirdest-Android-Phones-of-2010

That site states that there was a 2.55" diagonal screen in 2010:

> The Sony-Ericsson Xperia X10 Mini has only a 2.55" diagonal screen,
>   but it really is a full Android phone. Sony have to shrink the "home"
>   size from 4x4 to 3x3, and create some fancy UI to make the touchscreen
>   phone work with just a thumb, but it is currently the smallest Android
>   Phone.

Which when you look-up that phone you will see that it's screen resolution comes out to: `240 x 320 pixels (QVGA)`.

*Source: http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/corporate/products/phoneportfolio/specification/xperiax10mini*